# A MySQL IF condition

Tags: mysql, database, if-statement

In my query I have an IF statement:

```
IF(friend.block, 'yes', 'no')
```

where friend.block value is 0 or 1.. but either way its putting 'yes'.. any idea?

Comment: what is the type of friend.block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Reference: [MySQL Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if-statement.html)

The syntax is:

```
IF (friend.block = 1) THEN
    'Yes'
ELSE
    'No'
END IF
```

You can use case statement:

> CASE friend.block WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes'
>   WHEN 0 THEN 'No' END

Comment: Still doesn't explain why his if function didn't work, see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if

Answer (score 7):

`friend.block` should be of type `INTEGER` for that to work or you have to put a comparaison there:

```
IF(friend.block != 0, 'yes', 'no')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE friend.block WHEN 1 THEN 'yes' WHEN 0 THEN 'no' END
```