# Checking IP address using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am writing a thumb up/down rating system on items, The rating system should allow the user to rate only one time. I have an SQL table in the database named **rating** with columns : **id, itemname, commentno**. and another table **ip_check** that has : **id, commentno, ip.**

The commentno will be a foreign key and the syntax to get the ip should be like this : `<?php $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>` as I checked on line on several links like [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/472118/GetplusIPplusAddressplususingplusPHP).

Now what is the proper and easiest way to add a mysql if condition. I checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554313/a-mysql-if-condition) as well but I am still looking for something more specific, any help on this?

Comment: What is the benefit? Don't you receive enough security not allowing a single user to vote more than once? What if more than one user is at an address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For saving and in Mysql I recommended use Mysql function [INET_NTOA()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-ntoa) and [INET_ATON()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton)

For validating and get IP address I using this functions:

```
function is_ip($ip) {
    global $localIPs;
    $test = 0;
    $pattern='/^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[0-9])$/';
    $ip = explode(',', $ip);
    $ip = array_map('trim', $ip);
    foreach ($ip as $key => $value) {
        if(array_search($value, $localIPs)===false && preg_match($pattern, $value)) $test = $value;
    }
    if(!empty($test)) return $test;
    else return false;
}

function get_ip() {
    $ip='';
    if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP']) && is_ip($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'])) $ip=is_ip($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP']);
    elseif(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']) && is_ip($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) $ip=is_ip($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']);
    elseif(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) && is_ip($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) $ip=is_ip($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']);
    else $ip=is_ip($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    return $ip;
}
```